# Android - Theme Alert Dialogs

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm currently trying to implement themes into my application, and I'm running into issues when trying to style my Dialogs.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    ...
    <!-- AppCompat Dialog Attributes -->
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlert</item>
</style>
```

For example, MyTheme sets the colorPrimary and colorBackground correctly, which works fine in most areas of the app. And when I need to reference them I'm using them like this.

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="?android:colorBackground"
...>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    ... />
```

However, when I'm styling my dialogTheme and alertDialogTheme, the color seems to default to something else.

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

This will not use my defined colorBackground, but instead some light-grey ( default?) color.

[image: Example of styling]

Here is an example of the result.

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

Left side ("Desired") is using normal colors such as `@color/colorAccent` and the right side ("Result") is what happens if I attempt to use the theme colors `?colorAccent`.

How do I reference my theme's colors in styles correctly?

---

Also, somewhat related question, I'm trying to style my toolbar, but it's having no effect.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    ...
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/toolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="toolbarStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_background</item>
</style>
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Add Screen shots if possible so we can get idea about error.

Comment: I added an image to show what I'm getting using the theme method for referencing the colors. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for more info. If you want to perform such operations then use **DialogFragment**. They are same as dialog but you will have more controls over it.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are creating and showing the dialog?

Comment: All I'm doing is `new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);`, passing in the style I'm defining above. Perhaps I should be using `ContextThemeWrapper` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to at least theme the background of dialogs in API >= 23 by setting this attribute in the Activity's Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating">@color/gunmetal</item>
</style>
```

Then making sure your activity uses it in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="package.your.YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When extending `DialogFragment` use `AppCompatDialogFragment` instead and in your theme

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorBackgroundFloating">your_desired_color</item>
</style>
```

without the `android` prefix.

Tested for API 21+